# Update value in ListView Item

Tags: c#, xml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView of posts, I need to change the like button image source when clicked.

My XML is

```
<ListView x:Name="MessageView" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Margin="10, 10, 10, 0" Padding="10, 10, 15, 10">
                            <Image Source="options_icon.png" HeightRequest="15" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0, 0, 10, 0">
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding LikeClick}"/>
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

It is binded with

```
LikeClick = new Command(() => LikeMessage(navigation, message.Id)),
```

The LikeMessage method is

```
public static async Task LikeMessage(INavigation navigation, int id)
    {
*Web Request*


        if (page_result.Equals("liked"))
        {
           //Update source to "liked_icon.png"
        }

        if (page_result.Equals("unliked"))
        {
            //Update source to "like_icon.png"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the method triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give a name to your `<StackLayout>` element,

```
<StackLayout x:Name="Item" BackgroundColor="White" Margin="10, 10, 10, 0" Padding="10, 10, 15, 10">
```

Second, inside your list the tap gesture should like below,

```
 <TapGestureRecognizer BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference MessageView}, Path=BindingContext}"   Command="{Binding LikeClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference Item}, Path=BindingContext}"/>
```

Third, Bind your image source as well,

```
     <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" HeightRequest="15" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0, 0, 10, 0">
```

Forth, Inside your viewmodel class set `ImageSource` to the source you want to change.

Comment: I tried implementing it ( https://pastebin.com/nBAPaGWN ) but I cant figure out how to edit it in the LikePost method, I'm guessing Im suppose to pass the variable through the LikeMessage constructor but I can't find any variables from the XML

Comment: LikePost is suppose to say LikeMessage *typo*

Comment: Here, in this line `CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference Item}, Path=BindingContext}"` the x:reference name should be `MessageLayout` not the, "Item"

Comment: For an example `  LikeClick = new Command(async (e) => await LikeMessage(e));` and inside method you can get the list view object like ` var item = (e as PostObject);`

Comment: Where is the "e" in LikeMessage gotten from?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to your `MessageObject` class and do as below

Update your class

```
public string _Source;
public string Source
{
    get { return _Source; }
    set
    {
        _Source = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Source));
    }
}
```

Command bind should like this:

```
LikeClick = new Command(() => LikeMessage(navigation, message)),
```

Bind image source

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source}"
```

And last set in LikeMessage()

```
if (message.Source == "like_icon.png")
   message.Source = "liked_icon.png";
else
   message.Source = "like_icon.png";
```

Comment: On the line with "OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Source));" I am getting OnPropertyChanged name doesn't exist in current context